# getting strange errors after implementing "Introduction to In-App Purchases" tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios

I am  trying to implement in app purchasing , I followed this great tutorial [Introduction to In-App Purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

when I clean the project it shows no errors , but when I build the project it gives me these errors :

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PDF_Product.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PDF_Product.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InAppRageIAPHelper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in PDF_Product.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to remove the files and add them again , but did not work .
any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

They are linker errors showing that you have used classes that aren't being built into your final binary (and they;'re not in any frameworks etc).

For each class missing class, find the .m file that defines it (for example, 'Reachability` is probably defined in Reachability.m) and check :

- Have you definitely got Reachability.m in your app's target?
- Have you definitely got Reachability.m in your 'compile sources' build phase of your target?
- As @Sohaib mentioned below, is the correct membership checkbox selected? Check this in the properties inspector on the right hand side panel, in the left-most tab (the one that looks like a bit of paper) there's a section called 'Target membership' - this shows which targets your files are being compiled into. I'm always accidentally adding files into my unit tests target by mistake :)

Comment: I just drag and drop them inside my class . is that not correct wat to do it ?

Comment: It means these files aren't part of your target. Easy way to fix this is to remove these files and add to your project again and make sure on the right side your app's target check box is checked. Sometimes target check box is unchecked by default.